# Gaussian square-free moat

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, percolation, square-free

> Is there a sequence $\{z_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of distinct square-free
>   Gaussian integers with $$\sup_{n \geq 1} |z_{n+1} - z_n| < \infty ?$$

For the analogous problem with Gaussian primes instead, click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_moat).

Comment: The [percolation threshold of the square lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_threshold#Thresholds_on_Archimedean_lattices) is roughly smaller than 0.6, while the [density of squarefree Gaussian integers](http://oeis.org/A088454) is approximately 0.66. So, if the squarefree Gaussian integers were randomly distributed, there would be an infinite component with probability 1.